# Having trouble getting my location to update

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

A `ViewController` starts a LocationTracking. I want to NSLog the location updates (when the simulator is on freeway drive), but `didUpdateLocations` only logs when I uncomment the `NSTimer`, I can't figure out why. I feel real dumb asking this, it's probably something simple, I'm new to this and have spent a long time trying to work it out.

```
ViewController:

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults boolForKey:@"locationUpdate"]) {
        LocationTracking *locationTracker = [[LocationTracking alloc] init];
        [locationTracker startTracking];
        NSLog(@"location tracking did");
        //NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:locationTracker selector:@selector(logLast) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }

}
```

LocationTracking.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationTracking : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *locations;
-(void) startTracking;
-(void) logLast;

@end
```

LocationTracking.m:

```
#import "LocationTracking.h"

@interface LocationTracking()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation LocationTracking

-(void)startTracking
{
    self.locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"did update %@",[locations lastObject]);
}

-(void)logLast
{

}
```

Comment: didUpateLocations getting called for one time or not?

Comment: when the timer is firing (not commented out), didUpdateLocations updates and logs every time the location is updated. But when the timer is commented out, it doesn't log at all, and so I don't think it fires or gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works fine for me:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import CoreLocation;

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *loc = [locations lastObject];
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",loc.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",loc.coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"location is: %@, %@",lat,lon);
}


@end
```

And if you are using the simulator in Xcode, don't forget to set the location for the simulator. It defaults to "None" for new projects.

Comment: I don't actually want to use the NSTimer at all but right now it only works if I have it (calling an empty method), I want the didUpateLocations method to produce the logs. Changing it to self ceased all logging, same as commenting it out.

Comment: Do you actually `#import "LocationTracking.h"` into your `ViewController.m`? I don't see that in your example code.

Comment: @Gavin If he did not included "LocationTracking.h" in ViewController. how come code getting compile ?

Comment: I imported it into the ViewController.h, which is imported into the .m

Comment: @amk26cap I posted some example code in my answer that works fine for me. It continuously logs the location from the simulator in Xcode 5.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up scrapping the two-different-classes thing and just implemented it all in the viewcontroller, like you did

Comment: @amk26cap Well if my answer helps, please accept it or let me know if there is anything else I can help with.